# How to Insert 1 million items of data in database in more efficient way?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Main()
{
     WinOpTableAdapters.attendanceTableAdapter tx;
     tx = new WinOpTableAdapters.attendanceTableAdapter();

     Thread th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Insrt));  //thread
     th.Start();
}

void Insrt()
{
    WinOpTableAdapters.attendanceTableAdapter tx;
    tx = new WinOpTableAdapters.attendanceTableAdapter();

    for (int j = 0; j <= 100000; j++)
    {
        tx.InsertQueryAttend("Admin" + j);
    }
}
```

I want to insert 1 million items of data into a database in more efficient way, the code shown takes 5 mins to insert 5000 rows into database

Comment: are you using Entity framework ?

Comment: Look up `SqlBulkCopy`.

Answer (score 0):

[SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) is the best method to copy large amounts of data into a database. Some examples for `SqlBulkCopy`

- [Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy)
- [SQL-Bulk-Copy-with-C-Net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16922/SQL-Bulk-Copy-with-C-Net)

If you are using Entity Framework, https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162325/311255