# How to efficiently invoke table-valued parameters from Ado.Net

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I need to efficiently submit tens of thousands of numbers and dates from Ado.Net to SQl Server 2008. Back in the days, before SQL 2008, I was packing those numbers in an image, which was quite fast. Erland Sommarskog was kind enough to include some of my code in his article [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

Because now we can use TVPs, I tried them out. On the client, I am running this:

```
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(decimal));
        dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { someDate, somePrice });
            command.CommandText = "Writers.SavePrices";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var param = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prices", dataTable);
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
```

This code works, but I don't think it is efficient. I fired up the Profiler, and I immediately saw that Ado.Net issues the following highly inefficient SQL being sent to the server:

```
DECLARE @Prices TABLE(...)
INSERT INTO @Prices(...)VALUES(...)
EXEC Writers.SavePrices @Prices=@Prices
```

As a result, a lot of network bandwidth and CPU on the server is wasted on sending, parsing, and compiling. Is there a more efficient way to use TVPs with Ado.Net?

Comment: Do you know [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)? It's very efficient and flexible.  [Here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/use-sqlbulkcopy-to-quickly-load-data-from-your-client-to-sql-server) is an example.

Comment: @Tim: sure, I can use SqlBulkCopy to pour my data into a staging table. However, i cannot figure out a way to have SqlBulkCopy and TVPs work together.

Comment: I mentioned it as an alternative to TVP. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149897/performance-of-bcp-bulk-insert-vs-table-valued-parameters) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149897/performance-of-bcp-bulk-insert-vs-table-valued-parameters)   for more interesting infos about SQLBulkCopy compared to TVP.

Comment: @Tim: can you copy your comment into an answer, so that I can accept it? Apparently there is no better way.

Comment: Is ADO.NET sending tens of thousands of `INSERT` statements (one `INSERT` for each row in the TVP) as described in [this blog post](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/BOBB/post/The-interesting-case-of-TVPs-and-plan-compilation.aspx)?

Comment: @NickChammas: this blog post is precisely what the Profiler is telling me: one INSERT per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)? It's very efficient and flexible. [Here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/use-sqlbulkcopy-to-quickly-load-data-from-your-client-to-sql-server) is an example.

I mentioned it as an alternative to TVP. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149897/performance-of-bcp-bulk-insert-vs-table-valued-parameters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149897/performance-of-bcp-bulk-insert-vs-table-valued-parameters) for more interesting infos about SQLBulkCopy compared to TVP.

*(copied from comments)*